# What are the proper terms for those types of software combinations?

Tags: licensing, linking, combined-work, bundling

I am writing a python app and I am using external open source dependencies in 2 different ways:
A) standard import
B) calling an executable as a subprocess

What is the proper language to refer to such 'software combinations'?

Typical words I've seen used in that context are: derivative work, separate work, bundle, static link, dynamic link...

Comment: The first three terms you list are related to copyright, and last two are related to software compilation.  Can I ask if the question you've asked, which relates to nomenclature, is the real question you want answered, or whether you really want to know about your copyright licence obligations when performing tasks A and B?

Comment: For case B, normally software developers refer to such a program as a "front-end" for B, or a "launcher" for B.  Whether your software must be open sourced as a result of the license B in such a case depends on the details, e.g. whether or not you are distributing B, for example, and what the license is.